# can't find javascript error

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I would like to add new attribute to select box which name and id are 'firm_id'. So far I have tried with this code, its working fine in mozila but not working in IE.

I am doing this with javascript because select box is coming from ajax.
The function sbmtfrm() is not calling in IE.

**Error:** Message: 'FB' is undefined.

May be FB is a object called in my js lib files, but now i am writing code within a another saperate script  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function sbmtfrm()
    {
       alert('now submitting...');
       document.frmsearch.submit();
    }

    function setOnclickAtt(name)
    {
        alert("'"+name+"'" + document.getElementById(name).getAttribute('onchange'));
        alert(document.getElementById(name));
        if(document.getElementById(name))
        {
            alert('attrr changed');
            var ref = document.getElementById(name);
            ref.setAttribute('onchange', 'sbmtfrm();');
            alert("now new atrr = " + document.getElementById(name).getAttribute('onchange'));
        }
        else
        {
            alert('again');
            setTimeout("setOnclickAtt('firm_id')",100);
        }
    }

    setOnclickAtt('firm_id');

</script>
```

Any suggestion or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: IE doesn't like whatever FB is, it errors and so will not execute subsequent javascript. You need to fix the FB problem wherever it is.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you're using another script tag. Seach for FB in your project files and check its use by JS scripts.

Comment: but why this code block is not running, other functions are calling correctly ?

Comment: why function setOnclickAtt(name) calling and working, And sbmtfrm() not calling nor working

Answer (score 1):

I think IE is picky when it comes to event handling. Try:

```
ref.onchange = sbmtfrm;
```

instead of:

```
ref.setAttribute('onchange', 'sbmtfrm();');
```

Also, I think the error message has nothing to do with this issue. It´s wrong but it´s another issue.

Comment: Maybe you could put up some minimum viable code on http://jsfiddle.net/ so we could fix it.

Comment: Acctually now code is working fine but a doubt is that you can see that i have alerted after setting the new attribute "now new atrr = sbmtfrm()", but its getting old attribute, why so i dont know but working fine. :) Nice

Comment: My guess is that event handling is in many cases _magic_ and do not behave like normal attributes.